# How to paint through all mesh during vertex painting?

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

Tell please how to paint all vertices, not just visible, in vertex paint mode?

Comment: You should be able to do this in wireframe mode. Shortcut: Z

Comment: Thanks for answer, but doesnt work. What I need is functionality of "limit selection to visible" toggle in weight paint mode for vertex paint. But I cant find this button in vertex paint mode, cant believe such simple thing is not available by default...

Answer (score 2):

`Set Vertex Colors` (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) would do the trick.

### Painting whole model in one color

In `Vertex paint` mode select a color and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

### Painting a part of a model in one color

In `Edit mode` select what needs to be painted with `Limit selection to visible` button unchecked.

[image]

In `Vertex Paint` mode press `Face selection masking for painting` button, select color and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to paint only selected vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is to use the [Weights to Vertex Colors addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?290390-Weights-to-Vertex-Colors-addon) . It's not a real solution, just a workaround, but since you can paint through the mesh in weight paint mode by unchecking "Limit Selection to Visible" [image: 1], you can paint there and then convert your weights into vertex colors. But of course it converts it in greyscale (although there's an option to use the rainbow ramp from the weight painting but that's not usable for most textures).

But I think a "Limit to Visible" option in Vertex Paint should definitely be added in Blender.